How to add .tlb files (Type Libraries) to C# .csproj without Visual Studio?
I have to add one library with .tlb extension to my .csproj. Since in work I don't have Visual Studio license (because I usually work with other programming languages), I tried to use VS Code for this task and configure .csproj file.
I tried to use solution from this post: VSCode c# add reference to custom assembly
    <ItemGroup>
     <Reference Include="DllComunVb2008">
       <HintPath>..\win_b64\code\bin\InfTypeLib.tlb</HintPath>
     </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>

using INFITF;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

but it doesn't work, I get an error:
error CS1529: A using clause must precede all other elements defined in the namespace except extern alias declarations

I tried also another way from here How to reference an assembly(*.dll) without visual studio?:
<ProjectReference Include="C:\Program Files\Dassault Systemes\B31SP3PRALL\win_b64\code\bin\InfTypeLib.tlb" />

But it also doesn't seem to work
Do you have an idea how to add .tlb libraries to .csproj?

You can use regasm.exe if you have the framework installed: regasm mydll.dll/tlb:com.mydll.tlb

I think you need to convert it to a interop assembly to be able to use it from .Net. Not sure if there is a easy way to do that without VS.
